# Why IIS throws error while IIS Express not?

Tags: iis, com, iis-express, office-addins, visio

It's about a simple Web API code that should to:

1. Get vsdx file
2. Convert the file to svg by Visio
3. Sends back the file

The issue is that the same code works well when run by IIS Exspress but throws exception when run on IIS.
The problematic code is:

`Visio.Document doc = visioInvisibleApp.Documents.Open(vsdxSourcePath);`

I getting error with almost no info:

- **$exception**    {"\n\nAn exception occurred."}  System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
  Data    {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal} System.Collections.IDictionary {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
- ...
- **Message**   "\n\nAn exception occurred."

**Can somone help me please?**

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3 You are doing Office automation on IIS so doomed to fail.

Comment: Thanks. So, what is the recommended way to host/run Web API on server for production environment? and just to be sure,  you say that there is no way to host Web API on IIS and cause to it works well?

Comment: Visio, as a part of Microsoft Office, is not designed to be run server-side. Moreover, this sort of usage may be prohibited by it's license. Read this Microsoft KB article: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2

Comment: Nikolay, thanks a lot! very important things.

Comment: You can refer to this link about how to [Host ASP.Net Web API on IIS Server](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2b481f/how-to-host-Asp-Net-web-api-on-iis-server).

Comment: @Nikolay - I think you should put response in as an answer.

Comment: @PaulHerber it seems to be a commonly asked question... I think it's okay with the comment - since we can't do anything about it.. I've tried in the past, but it's not worth it IMHO, too many issues )